# How to integrate bootstrap template with typo3?

Tags: jquery, typo3, scriptaculous

How to integrate Bootstrap template with typo3, since bootstrap depends on JQuery and JQuery is in conflict with scriptaculous? I'm not quite sure if typo3 is the one using scriptaculous or is someone of the extensions i'm using.

Comment: What is `src` attribute of included scriptaculous file(s) ?

Comment: backend or frontend?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you stumbled upon this question: Current versions (7.6.x, 8.x) don't use scriptaculous and jQuery is only loaded in backend by default. If using jQuery or JS in backend, please use requireJS. Take a look at https://scripting-base.de/blog/requirejs-backend-1.html

For the frontend, use whatever you like as there is all done by you.

Answer (score 0):

You know that bootstrap doesn't depend on jQuery, right? You can just include the CSS and leave out the JS. In my experience, 99% of the value of Bootstrap is in the styling, and whenever I've needed to do anything dynamic, I've ended up rolling my own JS (jQuery) anyway.